# apt-get update backtrack repository

Tags: linux, repository, backtrack

I got error massages like failed to fetch, unable to connect:

With these source.list repositories. I even tried `http://50.7.240.6` and it joined but there were different errors.

I have Backtrack 5 r3, had same issue with r2. Is the problem that I'm running it on virtual box / vmware? I can connect to internet but I guess those repositories are outdated or something.

deb http://all.repository.backtrack-linux.org revolution main microverse non-free testing
    .  deb `http://32.repository.backtrack-linux.org` revolution main microverse non-free testing
    .  deb `http://64.repository.backtrack-linux.org` revolution main microverse non-free testing
    .  deb http://source.repository.backtrack-linux.org revolution main microverse non-free testing

Comment: well here are the errors if you can see the problem I'd be very glad pastebin.com/r3BxwDk8

Comment: Content require to help you should exist in the question itself.